# Incorrect resizing on h1 and navbar wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I've been fighting with a small(big) issue on a wordpress site all morning. I've tried adjusting margins, adding and adjusting an overflow attribute, adding media queries, and the lot. But it seems I can't get these elements to play nice with a minimized window.

[image: h1 being covered]
[image: Nav text not staying together]

As you can see, I just need the h1 text (Quiescent imaging...) to always stay visible and in place and I also need the text in the sidebar to stay together.

These issues also only occur with a minimized window.

Any tips are highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need to add some code to try and reproduce the issue, other way we can't suggest anything.

Comment: Sorry! The code itself is mostly WordPress short code. But I believe I found what the issue is. I'll add it to the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out this is a lot more simple than needing to edit any code. The h1 attribute, rather, **the title bar** I was trying to edit can be modified toward the bottom of the page editor which we are using (fusion builder).

I usually overlook these simple solutions, but I'll accept the embarrassment if this helps someone out one day!

[image: Titlebar editing section - Fusion builder]

More info:

**The Page Title Bar is not an Element;** rather it is controlled via the Theme Options and the Fusion Page Options. This article will look in depth at the options that are available for this *often overlooked tool.* 
https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/options/page-title-bar-options/